# How to change navigation bar title in UIImagePicker?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm writing in Swift, so there isn't enough info that I can find to address this.

Anyway, I have everything working fine, i.e.: photo library selection view presented, editing works fine and cropped image gets exported to an image view.

My problem is really when the view is presented modally, the title says "Photos". How do I change this to something else?

```
var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
imagePicker.navigationItem.title = "MY TITLE"
```

Changing the title text attributes work, but not changing the title itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make yourself the delegate of imagePicker and implement:

```
func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    viewController.navigationItem.title = "asdf"
}
```

found here: [Changing NavigationBar Title of UIImagePickerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716583/changing-navigationbar-title-of-uiimagepickercontroller)

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
                viewController.navigationItem.title = "asdf"
      }
```