# Adding System Camera on UIBarButton inside UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

If you are familiar with `UIImagePickerController` screen for `.PhotoLibrary`, on the right hand side there is a Cancel button. On the left hand side, I want to add a Camera icon that can be found in XCode library.

My code doesn't work.

```
let picker = UIImagePickerController()
picker.delegate = self
picker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
picker.allowsEditing = true

let camera = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Camera, target: picker, action: Selector("btnOpenCamera"))
picker.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = camera

presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referred to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716583/changing-navigationbar-title-of-uiimagepickercontroller), and interpret from objective C to Swift.

I found a solution to my question. This method will do whatever customisation I need inside a loaded view controller.

```
func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {

    let camera = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Camera, target: self, action: Selector("btnOpenCamera"))
    viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = camera
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may reset navigationItem to other somewhere else during code execution (for example in viewDidLayoutSubviews).

You can try to inherit from UIImagePickerController and reimplement

```
func viewWillAppear(animated:Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(animated)

let camera = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Camera, target: , action:self Selector("btnOpenCamera"))//you can handle this with delegate if you want
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = camera
}
```

Than just use your inherited class instead of standard UIImagePickerController. Hope it helped.

Comment: Actually that chunk of codes is inside my viewWillAppear method.

Comment: Ok but that is your viewWillAppear and I'm talking about inheriting UIImagePickerController - your viewWillAppear has no influence on picker controller. And last line of code should be changed, I will edit it to new one.

Comment: Inherited UIImagePickerController, but doesn't help

Comment: `class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerController` correct?

Comment: No, you need to do next steps:
1) create class MyOwnImagePickerController: UIImagePickerController
2) reimplement IN your MyOwnImagePickerController with my realization
3) in your view controller instead of using standard UIImagePickerController - use MyOwnImagePickerController

Comment: Ahhh... Ok. I will try it when I have access to my computer. It's weekend! Will let u know again! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi, tried your solution and it is giving me tons of errors. Such as multiple inheritance issues, delegate issues and etc. Anyway I've decided to do it another way. thanks!

Comment: It's giving you errors because you implemented it with errors. I can't write you all code for your project, you need to understand the main idea and insert it into your code logic. Why you think that copy-pasting code will help you to solve your bug. It wont give errors if you wont code with errors...

Comment: the problem is there isn't a need a new class to implement, a simple `func navigationController` willShowViewController method is the solution. Your solution is wrong in the first place.

Comment: Telling that this method is wrong.. you just didn't implement it correctly. All idea is to find method in lifecycle after which picker controller won't redefine its button. You founded this method, I advised you even later method to be sure that nothing won't be redefined. So if you can't understand why this works and where is the problem than pls don't say that something is not working and I gave you wrong advise, you just didn't implement it correctly to the end. This both solutions is the same just using other methods. They both are lifecycle methods and both would help to solve the problem