# Adding left UIBarButton in UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to add a Camera option on my left bar item inside `.PhotoLibrary` My codes as shown below, and they don't work.

```
let picker = UIImagePickerController()

let camera = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Camera, target: self, action: Selector("btnOpenCamera"))
picker.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = camera

picker.allowsEditing = true
picker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
picker.delegate = self

presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this the way you are doing because there is no `UINavigationController` to `UIImagePickerController`. In order to do this you must add `UIInavigationControllerDlegate` method in your class.

Add this method in your `viewController`

```
 func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        print("m in")

   viewController.navigationItem.title = "Home"
   let camera = UIBarButtonItem(title: "camera", style: .Plain, target:self, action:  "btnOpenCamera")
    viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = camera
```

The output is like this:
[image]

Comment: Found a solution on my own. Cannot use didShowViewController, because the second time it loads, it will not work. Should use willShowViewController. I needed a system image. Thanks for your answer though! Up your answer!

Comment: yup, i meant to will show...it was by mistake. will update it.

Answer (score 0):

Referred to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716583/changing-navigationbar-title-of-uiimagepickercontroller), and interpret from objective C to Swift.

I found a solution to my question. This method will do whatever customisation I need inside a loaded view controller.

```
func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {

    let camera = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Camera, target: self, action: Selector("btnOpenCamera"))
    viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = camera
}
```